# Setting up vuejs-template-webpack with docker doesn't reload after saving files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I just starting using docker I set up my project with vue js,
it works when I run `docker-compose up` but it doesn't save after I save any file..it's not listening

**docker-compose logs**

```
web_1  | yarn run v1.10.1
web_1  | $ webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js --host 0.0.0.0
web_1  |  84% module id optimiza  DONE  Compiled successfully in 4455ms15:29:27
web_1  |
web_1  |  I  Your application is running here: http://localhost:8080
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:    
    build: ${CONTAINER_ROOT}/web/
    command: yarn run dev
    volumes:
    - ${PROJECT_ROOT}:/var/www

    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

**.env**

```
CONTAINER_ROOT=./docker-containers
PROJECT_ROOT=./www
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:9.11.1-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server
RUN npm install -g yarn


WORKDIR /var/www/src

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN yarn

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
RUN yarn run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

================ update ================

**terminal output**

**docker-compose config**

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: /Users/xxxxxxx/Documents/dev/node-static-vue-template/docker-containers/web
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
    - 8080:8080/tcp
    volumes:
    - /Users/xxxxxxxxx/Documents/dev/node-static-vue-template/www:/var/www:rw
version: '3.0'
```

any idea what would it be ?
am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

A `.env` file doesn't guarantee them being set at runtime. A .env file is run and read by the `dotenv` npm package and doesn't really have much to do with docker. Have you exported the variables prior to running a `docker-compose build`? As your docker-compose is using environment variables but a `.env` file only works with node runtime as far as I know.

So if you're running linux/mac you can just run 
`export CONTAINER_ROOT=./docker-containers` (note the no spacing)
Repeat this for the project_root as well. This should be done on the command line you are running `docker-compose build` from. N.B. Env variables set this way are not permanent and are reset after every restart of the terminal.

A quick fix to this problem is just to hardcode it and to see if the volumes are working correctly as intended and then to implement the volumes.

Also you can use linux commands like `pwd` to get the document root it might be easier than a custom env variable.

Also you're using a package-lock.json which is npm specific -> yarn uses a yarn.lock file? To reduce bloatware and the size of the docker container I would suggest just using `npm run build` instead of installing and using yarn. It's probably easier and will use your package-lock.json.

I hope this has answered your question!

Comment: thanks for your comment... I siwch to npm like you said but still the same when I type `docker-compose config` it shows an output of the `docker-compose.yml` with the variables..I'm going to put on the question

Comment: What operating system are you using ?

Comment: Also when I've used build, I've just used a relative path to the docker-compose.yml i.e. `. or ./src`

Comment: I also just checked for volumes, I have also used a relavtive path instead of a full path see https://github.com/Mortuie/FreeCodeCamp/blob/master/backend/votingapp/docker-compose.yaml for more details and a fully working docker-compose.yaml with builds and custom volumes

Comment: Also you should really have a dev and prod dockerfile. The dockerfile above is for static generation and not really suited to running a webpack dev server. In the github folder above I have done the same `webpack-dev-server` with react and it hot reloads look at that example if you're interested.